# Azure AD B2C App Registration Graph API -- Clarification

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

So, I am trying to utilize Graph API with Azure AD B2C. My understanding is that it's not possible to use the `client_credentials` flow when requesting access tokens. When I try to utilize an access token with `client_credentials` to get `/beta/policies/b2cAuthenticationMethods` I receive this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AADB2C",
    "message": "User Authorization: Access is denied.",
    "innerError": {
      "correlationId": "4c00031f-febc-4c1a-9728-701f0c1fda00",
      "date": "2021-01-19T18:51:42",
      "request-id": "77a30adb-5103-40ec-84f3-0626800e976a",
      "client-request-id": "77a30adb-5103-40ec-84f3-0626800e976a"
    }
  }
}
```

Which is expected since I used the client_credentials flow.

But, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga) states the following:

> Although the OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow is not currently
> directly supported by the Azure AD B2C authentication service, you can
> set up client credential flow using Azure AD and the Microsoft
> identity platform /token endpoint for an application in your Azure AD
> B2C tenant. An Azure AD B2C tenant shares some functionality with
> Azure AD enterprise tenants.

I have gone through the process linked above. However, I am running into one issue and now have questions about this "automated" process:

#### Question: How do I complete this automated process for requesting and utilizing access tokens with a registered app in B2C if I cannot use the client_credentials flow?

I cannot have any user interaction when this application requests an access token.

Do I have to use a different flow? If so, how do I do it so that things like MFA aren't an issue? I am not using any SDKs, I am just directly querying MGraph using an `HttpClient` in my application with the `Authorization Bearer` header passed.

#### Issue

Why am I not able to complete [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga#enable-user-delete-and-password-update) of the above linked documentation.

I am logged in as a global admin for my B2C tenant. I navigate to the `Roles and Administrators` section

[image]

Then, in the `Add Assignments` popup that appears on the left I start typing the name of my app

[image]

and it does not appear! But it is registered, and  I can see it in my list of registered applications:

[image: -]

What is the deal here?

I have found many other questions similar, and all have led me to the referenced documentation page. But, I still am not quite understanding the correct procedure to automatically get an access token for a registered app in B2C tenants.

Thanks so much.

#### Edit

See my answer for both solutions to the problems I had in this post.

Okay, so I managed to find the answer to my issue [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/229991/azure-ad-b2c-application-won39t-show-up-as-an-opti.html).

Just out of curiosity, I made that ServicePrincipal for my application a Global admin. I used the `client_crededentials` flow again to the `beta/policies/b2cAuthenticationMethodsPolicy` and STILL received that above error about User Authorization: Access is dened. What the heck? I'm starting to wonder if it's that specific endpoint that's the issue, and not the flow itself. Especially because I can get `/beta/users` just fine when using the access token from `client_credentials` flow for my B2C tenant.

Comment: So you have find the answer right? If yes, could you add an answer to help others who may have the same issue?

Comment: @AllenWu I did not find the complete answer. Only part of it. I find out why I was not able to add my service principal in the azure portal. But I’m still having issues with the question I my post.

Comment: Firstly, Using [Azure AD client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to access Microsoft Graph of B2C is supported. But, as you have tested, it seems that the beta endpoint for Application permission (client_credentials) has **NOT** been available although the documentation indicates that it is supported. `/beta` version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change. Please continue to look forward to the improvement of this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have found my answers.

To my issue:

I found the answer on this thread https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/229991/azure-ad-b2c-application-won39t-show-up-as-an-opti.html.

To my question:

I opened an issue on the MSFT Docs GitHub page, and someone was able to answer my question [there](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/69157#issuecomment-763588897).